# Supplying 1 JDBC request result to multiple threads in JMeter

Tags: json, jdbc, jmeter

I'm facing an issue in Jmeter. The API I am testing, get the parameters from a prior JDBC request.
This works fine when there is only 1 thread. But, when I run multiple threads it throws the error below

```
{"Message": "A transient error has occurred. Please try again. (1205)","Data":null}
```

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zbel7.png)

I need to run 5 threads without having to run the JDBC request 5 times. 
I can retrieve 5 results in 1 JDBC call and supply them sequentially for each of the thread. Is this possible? How can I do this?
Worst-case scenario I will have to manually set up CSV file instead of JDBC calls.

Comment: Show your JDBC configuration

Answer (score 0):

Normally people use [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test/) for test data preparation and [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) for eventual clean-up. I would suggest moving your JDBC Request under the setUp Thread Group and run it with 1 virtual user.

---

If you have to keep the test plan structure as it is and can amend the SQL query to return more results, be aware that according to the [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler documentation the results look like:

```
myVar_#=5
myVar_1=foo
myVar_2=bar
myVar_3=baz
myVar_4=qux
myVar_5=corge
```

Therefore you can use the values using [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) and [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) functions combination like:

```
${__V(myVar_${__threadNum},)}
```